# Python using lambda sort list or dicts by multiple keys

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

here is my list of dict:

```
l = [{'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 3}, 
     {'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'b': 1}, 
     {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 3},
     {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, 
     {'a': 2, 'c': 5, 'b': 3}]
```

and now I want to sort the list by keys and orders provided by the user. for instance:

```
keys = ['a', 'c', 'b']
orders = [1, -1, 1]
```

I tried to using lambda in `sort()`method but it failed in a weird way :

```
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: (order * x[key] for (key, order) in zip(keys, orders)))
>>> l
[{'a': 2, 'c': 5, 'b': 3},
 {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2},
 {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 3},
 {'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'b': 1},
 {'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 3}]
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Please define 'weird' more precisely. Weird in what way?

Answer (score 5):

You were almost there; your `lambda` produces generator expressions and those happen to be ordered by their memory address (in Python 2) and produce a `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'generator' and 'generator'` exception in Python 3.

Use a list comprehension instead:

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: [order * x[key] for (key, order) in zip(keys, orders)])
```

Demo:

```
>>> l = [{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 3},
...      {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2},
...      {'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 3},
...      {'a': 2, 'c': 5, 'b': 3},
...      {'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'b': 1}]
>>> keys = ['a', 'c', 'b']
>>> orders = [1, -1, 1]
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: [order * x[key] for (key, order) in zip(keys, orders)])
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(l)
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 2},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 5},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 3},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 1}]
```

Comment: @WangNick: Ah, you are still returning generators, but you are probably using Python 2.